# sort based on column

Tags: sort

```
10 awhdk;
14 hjoeow;
2  kdkld;
4  jkjdksl
```

How to sort this based on column one (i.e the count) ?

I'd want to get this output :

`14 hjoeow;10 awhdk;4 jkjdksl;2 kdkld`

I need both the columns to be printed based on sorting the first column.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-k` to specify where in the input line the sort key starts and ends.

You use the `-n` option or add `n` to the sort key specification to trigger a numeric sort as opposed to a lexical sort by default. And `-r` to reverse the sort.

Here, for a numerical sort, you don't need to limit the sort key to the sort command. If you do:

```
sort -rn file
```

It will treat the whole line as a number. The `14 hjoeow;` line for instance will be understood as the `14` number.

You could do:

```
sort -bk 1,1rn file
```

To sort on the first field only, but that would make no difference.

The command to join lines is `paste` with the `-s` option. You can specify the delimiter with `-d`. `\0`  is a special value for the delimiter that means *join with nothing in between*. So, to get your expected output:

```
sort -rn file | paste -sd '\0' -
```

POSIX `paste` require a filename be passed. `-` is again a special value that means *standard input*. You can omit it with some `paste` implementations.

Comment: @arun if this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.